# List windows shares/computers

Tags: ubuntu, samba, smb

On Ubuntu, how can I get a list of all windows machines/shares on the network?  I tried smbclient, but it only seems to list the shares of a known machine.

Answer (score 4):

Use [smbtree](http://linux.die.net/man/1/smbtree):

```
marco@hostname:~$ smbtree
Enter marco's password:
NETWORKNAME
    \\HOST_1        hostname
        \\HOST_1\RESOURCE1    comment 
        \\HOST_1\RESOURCE2    comment 
        ...
    .
    .
    .
    \\HOST_N        hostname
        \\HOST_N\RESOURCE1    comment 
        \\HOST_N\RESOURCE2    comment 
        ...
```

Comment: Please give an example of how smbtree works and possibly simple code to follow.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer but usually smbtree is used without options.

Comment: You can use smbtree -N to avoid using password.